# Longtail video php API integration issue

Tags: javascript

Looking to integrate the longtail php(bits on the run) video API into an application ,i want to be able to retrieve all the keys from the content server and associate them with a column in my mysql database song_id, and use an anchor tag with a query string to be able to retrieve the correct video when click on . Pretty much confuse how to do the integration .after calling the API , an array was return. .how to i query the API to be able to access all the key?

```
$response = $botr_api->call("/videos/list",array('video_key'=>$video_key));
if ($response['status'] == "error") { die($response); }

Array
(
    [status] => ok
    [video] => Array
        (
            [status] => ready
            [sourceurl] => 
            [description] => 
            [tags] => Kompa
            [views] => 1
            [title] => Pou'n Ale
            [sourceformat] => 
            [mediatype] => video
            [custom] => Array
                (
                )

            [duration] => 263.37
            [upload_session_id] => 
            [link] => 
            [author] => 
            [key] => ZLMzClv9
            [error] => 
            [date] => 1356543180
            [md5] => c12663ebc91858f8223d7d2673048bdb
            [sourcetype] => file
            [size] => 388334729
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<video onClick="if( this.paused) this.play(); else this.pause();">
```

You can of course improve it (for instance, using a proper callback rather than an inline event), and do more with it (show/hide the Play button), but this is it in its simplest form.

Comment: thanks for the advice ,i'm not too good with javascript , do you know any available script that can accomplish that without too much complexity. thanks